# Ubuntu installer doesn't see windows partition

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

### The problem:

I have Windows installed, i wanted to install ubuntu too, but when i go to the installer, it doesn't see the existing partitions, it shows the whole 500GB of the hard drive as free space and it wants to install ubuntu on the whole hardrive.

### The background:

I have changed the original hard drive of my laptop with one that came from a mac, i formatted it and installed windows there.

### Now what?

I am suspecting some issue related to MBR (and GPT?), but what should i do? All i want is a dual boot win and ubuntu. Another smaller hint that is puzzling me for a while is that while i am on windows, i get the option to unmount except from any other portable hard drive or USB, the C as well! I never tried it though...

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue once. I was told to try another CD because there was probably a problem with gparted. Didn't work so I just manually made another partition at the "end" of the hard drive and prayed it wouldn't eat into my files. It worked.